# Behavior of repaint() when painting circles on a JComponent

Tags: java, swing

I had an assignment about making painting circles on a JComponent when I click on it and that if you click on an existing circle, it will print a message. Everything works fine, except that the first circle that I draw will have a black border when the following ones wont.

I think it has to do with the repaint method but I cant seems to find what is going on.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GraphComponent extends JComponent {

    private int defaultWidth = 500;
    private int defaultHeight = 500;
    protected Point spot;
    protected int width = 50;
    protected int height = 50;
    private ArrayList<Ellipse2D> shapeList = new ArrayList();

    public GraphComponent() {
        super();
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(defaultWidth,defaultHeight));

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                boolean contains = false;
                spot = e.getPoint();
                for (Shape shape : shapeList) {
                    if (shape.contains(spot)) {
                        System.out.println("WIN");
                        System.out.println();
                        contains = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(shapeList.contains(spot));
                if(contains == false){
                    shapeList.add(new Ellipse2D.Double(spot.x - width / 2,
                            spot.y - width / 2, width, height));
                }
                repaint();
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                //moveSquare(e.getX(),e.getY());
            }
        });
    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics gfx) {
        super.paintComponents(gfx);
        for (Ellipse2D shape : shapeList) {
            gfx.drawOval((int)shape.getX(), (int)shape.getY(),width,height);
            gfx.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            gfx.fillOval((int)shape.getX(), (int)shape.getY(),width,height);
        }
    }
}
```

I expect all the circles to look the same, yet the first created has black borders

[image: circles example]

Comment: Don't call `super.paintComponents` (with an s)! - you are supposed to call `super.paintComponent (without an s). If it doesn't exist, it means you are inheriting from a wrong class.

Comment: I don't see where `JavaFX` is used.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, You mean that I shouldn't inherits JComponent? And what are the difference between super.paintComponents and super.paintComponent?

Comment: No, I am saying you should use `paintComponent` as `paintComponents` is an entirely different method. To see the difference between them, check the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a unique `Graphics` object, so the first call (from the first iteration) to `drawOval` will paint with the default `Graphics` 's color, which is black .

Next iterations will all paint in yellow .

```
for (Ellipse2D shape : shapeList) {
    gfx.drawOval((int)shape.getX(), (int)shape.getY(),width,height);// BLACK (at first iteration, YELLOW for next ones)
    gfx.setColor(Color.YELLOW);// YELLOW (from now on)
    gfx.fillOval((int)shape.getX(), (int)shape.getY(),width,height);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, as simple as that.